# when i download the file from database then "failed to load" message display

Tags: php

I am trying to download the files from database. but it shows "failed to load" message.Uploading is working fine. i can upload pdf, jpg, dox file. but unable to open when i download.IF there are three href links in my file. first is for "upload" second is for "delete". every link download the file from image even other links are for other work but every file calls the downld.php file

```
<a href="downld.php?id=<?php echo $project_id;?>"><?php echo $name;?></a>


downld.php



<?php
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
$project_id = $_GET['id'];
$myConnection= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "extra") or die ("could 
not connect to mysql");
mysqli_set_charset($myConnection,'utf-8');
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT name, type, size, content " .
"FROM wp_postprojectwin WHERE project_id = $project_id";


$result = mysqli_query($myConnection,$sql) or die('Error, query failed');

list($name, $type, $size, $content) =  mysqli_fetch_array($result);
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');

header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

mysqli_close($connection);
ob_clean();
 flush();
echo $content;
exit;
}
else{

echo "sorry";


}

?>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should use [readfile($content);](http://php.net/readfile) instead of `echo($content)`? - Assuming `$content` contains the link towards the file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment :). but i have tried this code . its still not working.